# PJSIP project: the window handle created from pjsua allways NULL

Tags: c++, sdl, pjsip

In a PJSIP project (Windows 32 Bit MFC/C++) we are working with SIP server to show the incoming video call. 
Since using SDL / DirectShow (DirectX) layers, the SDL creates his own window to show incoming video (it works). My config_site.h looks like :

```
#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO           1
#define PJMEDIA_HAS_FFMPEG          1
#define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_SDL       1
#define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_DSHOW     1
```

I would have the video showed in own windows rather than in SDL's window.
So I try to get HWND of the SDL's window and to use it like a child window of own one:

```
pjsua_call_get_info(call_id, &ci);
for (unsigned i = 0; i < ci.media_cnt; ++i) 
{
  if ((ci.media[i].type == PJMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) && 
     (ci.media[i].dir & PJMEDIA_DIR_DECODING))
  {
    pjsua_vid_win_info wi;
    pjsua_vid_win_get_info(ci.media[i].stream.vid.win_in, &wi);
    // Using handle like this or whatever:
    //HWND hwndOld = ::SetParent((HWND)&wi.hwnd.info.win.hwnd, pWnd->m_hWnd);
    break;
  }
}
```

The problem: **wi.hwnd.info.win.hwnd** is allways NULL !

Maybe someone has the similar problem with SDL's windows? 
The question is also, whether I obviosly need a SDL layer - maybe I shall just drop it using solely PJSIP? I mean:

```
#define PJMEDIA_HAS_VIDEO           1
#define PJMEDIA_HAS_FFMPEG          1
//#define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_SDL       1
//#define PJMEDIA_VIDEO_DEV_HAS_DSHOW     1
```

I have tried this config but no video has been showed ...

Comment: Just to info: http://lists.pjsip.org/pipermail/pjsip_lists.pjsip.org/2011-November/013684.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround found (quick & dirty) - FindWindow helps (:

```
CWnd* pWnd = mainView->GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_CTRL);
RECT rectWin;
::GetWindowRect(pWnd->m_hWnd, &rectWin);

HWND hWnd = FindWindow( _T("SDL_app"), NULL);

::SetWindowPos(hWnd, 
        NULL, 
        rectWin.left, 
        rectWin.top, 
        rectWin.right - rectWin.left,
        rectWin.bottom - rectWin.top,
        SWP_SHOWWINDOW );
```